# TableLayout and layout_weight doesn't work

Tags: android, button, tablelayout, tablerow, android-layout-weight

Trying to build a calculator view using `weightSum=100` and `android:layout_weight` where regular button should be **25%** of the screen. How ever the **0 digit** `@+id/button18` button should be twice the size of a regular one so it is set as `android:layout_weight="50"` however it doesn't occupy the desired space. Why so?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:weightSum="100">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button13"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="74dp"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
               android:text="1"
               android:textSize="30sp" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button14"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
               android:text="2" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button15"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
               android:text="3" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button16"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/orange"
               android:text="+"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:textSize="30sp" />
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:weightSum="100">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button18"
               android:layout_height="74dp"
               android:layout_weight="50"
               android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
               android:text="0" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button15"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
               android:text="." />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button16"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="25"
               android:background="@color/orange"
               android:text="="
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:textSize="30sp" />
       </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are missing to set width to your **button18 & button15**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

but I am suggesting you to use `width="0dp"` instead `width="wrap_content"` for accuracy when you are setting weight to width.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Change all `Button`'s width `android:layout_width="0dp"` .

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:text="2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:text="3"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:text="0"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:text="."/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:text="="
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]